# SQL syntax error in find and replace sql

Tags: mysql

OK this is a question that I know has been answered many times, there must be something strange happening in my particular case. I have a table set up where there is a Title, Filename and Id column.

I need to replace every instance of \myimages\PICS\ in the filename column with images/images/. For some reason

The below code is what I have tried last, with no luck. It keeps throwing me the attached screen shot. http://screencast.com/t/dd7n07Cjs Any direction on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!!

```
UPDATE ez_images
SET FILENAME = REPLACE(FILENAME, 'C:\myimages\PICS\', 'images/images/')
;
```

Comment: maybe you need to escape the `\\`

Comment: Using a backslash doesn't mean a literal backslash in MySQL, it quotes the next character so that you - for example - can include a `'` in a string as `SELECT 'O\'Connor'`

Comment: please show a sample of the content of filename column and the result you want obtain ..

Comment: so currently in our filename column images\PICS\01021510.PDF would be a common field. what I needed it to be is https://www.URL.com/images/PICS/01021510.PDF

Answer (score 0):

You should use  this

```
 UPDATE  ez_images
 SET filename  = REPLACE(FILENAME, 'C:\myimages\PICS\\', 'images/images/')
 WHERE filename LIKE '%C:\myimages\PICS\\%';
```

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an escape character in MySQL, see [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html). In your case it means that the last single quote of the first string is a part of the string and not the closing quote of the "C:\myimages\PICS" string. To the server it looks like you're doing this (double quotes used to highlight the difference):

```
UPDATE ez_images
SET FILENAME = REPLACE(FILENAME, "C:\myimages\PICS\', "images/images/")
                  start of string^                 end^^             ^start of another string
                                                       |some code that doesn't conform to the syntax
```

That's also why even the stackoverflow code highlighter doesn't highlight the strings properly.